# how AWS cloudwatch works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-auto-scaling

I am just trying to understand how AWS cloudwatch works.

In a few EC2 instances I saw - AWS cloudwatch agent not running.

But still in cloudwatch dashboard I was able to see real time graphs for CPU; but disk,memory graph did not show.

And I read - AWS does not support disk,memory metrics by default. It needs to be added as custom metric..

so my understanding - if metrics supported by AWS default like CPU - they don't need cloudwatch agent running  .. and only custom metrics like memory,disk - needs cloudwatch agent running on respective instances, am I right??

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

Most AWS service send data to Amazon CloudWatch. For example, the Amazon EC2 service sends metric data to CloudWatch for instances that are running.

However, the EC2 service can only see the 'virtual machine' at a 'virtual hardware' level, so it only reports:

- CPU Utilization
- Read/Write operations to disks
- Network traffic

The Memory used within an instance is managed by the Operating System, as is the management of the actual data on the disk. Therefore, the Amazon EC2 service cannot see how much memory or disk is being used.

To add such metrics to CloudWatch you will need some software that is running *inside* the virtual machine that talks to the Operating System and checks free memory and disk space. The [Amazon CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) does exactly this -- it is a piece of software that grabs information from the Operating System and reports it back to CloudWatch.

The CloudWatch Agent is installed by default on Amazon Linux, or you can download it and install it on other instances (and even your own non-AWS computers). It can also be configured to **send log files** to Amazon CloudWatch Logs so that logs can be centrally stored and monitored.

Comment: so i got custom config to get memory metric and saved in "C:\ProgramData\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\Configs"

and verified aws cloudwatch agent running in my windows ec2 instance..
but still in cloudwatch dashboard my memory metric is emoty.. its not showing anything..

how do i troubleshoot this ?

Comment: Try [Troubleshooting the CloudWatch agent - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/troubleshooting-CloudWatch-Agent.html). Otherwise, please create a new Question that shows your configuration and explain that data is not appearing in CloudWatch. Also, include details about the Operating System (Windows? Amazon Linux?) and the Logs referenced on that page.